# Perform a web.config transform before publishing with MSBuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

I am trying to do a web deploy publish using MS Build for two web applications for internal use and testing.  I have set up different solution configurations for each of the environments that i want to publish to. IE DevA, DevB. I have updated all the web.configs to do the correct transformations.  As a note, the transforms work when i do a right click publish through Visual Studio so I have ruled those out as the problem. My current bat file that I am running uses this command to do the work:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild" project.csproj
>   /t:Clean;Rebuild;Publish
>   /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=DevB1_API;AllowUntrustedCertificate=True;username=username;password=password

When i run this command the publish works just fine. However, the web.config is not being transformed.  Am i missing a msbuild parameter to force this to happen?  Any Help would be appreciated!  thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apparently, for the transform to be executed, you have to specify a build configuration using:

> /p:Configuration=Release

Comment: You'd think that the publish profile would take care of this, since when you configure the publish profile, it asks you what configuration you want to build with...apparently that's not the case though. This answer saved me some time!